# Angular CLI - After refreshing in browser the browser try to load files from a wrong location

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular CLI application. If I navigate to an specific route and then trigger a refresh (F5 in the Browser), the browser try to load files from a wrong location.

[image]

So is it possible to define in the .angular-cli.json a base path? Or whats the right way here?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
If I add the following statement to the .angular-cli.json, the .js file will be loaded correctly. But fonts (e.g. ttf, woff, ...) will be loaded from the wrong location

```
"apps": [
{
    "baseHref": "/"
}]
```

Comment: By default the CLI should be fine did you modify it somehow?

Comment: Did you eject ?

Comment: I didn't modify any basic settings. I find out, that the problem only exists in chrome - in IE it works as expected. Is it possible, that urls to the fonts in the generated CSS file are incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the dev version, because I use angular/cli@next: [Github - AOT build error Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8434#event-1424422471)